# How to change active tab from other tab in case of using bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter

I need to add button like 'Go to other tab' and be able to navigate user from this tab to any other. Is it possible in case I use bottomNavigationBar approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It's just an `int` that holds the selected index. I provide you with a small example.

[image: example]

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _goToTab(int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _goToTab,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mail), title: Text('Item 1')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mood), title: Text('Item 2')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text('Item 3')),
        ],
      ),
      body: List.unmodifiable([
        Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _goToTab(1), child: Text('Go to tab 2'))),
        Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _goToTab(2), child: Text('Go to tab 2'))),
        Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _goToTab(0), child: Text('Go to to back to tab 1'))),
      ])[_selectedIndex],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In case my 'body-widgets' defined in-place I can use private method. But in case separated to other class? Some how through context? Maybe possible to get access to parent scaffold?

Comment: You can try to do do it by using a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` such as `final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key =GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
_key.currentContext` and then assigning it to your `Scaffold(key: _key)...`

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigationBar` has a property named `currentIndex` and you can assign a number and change that number on click with `setState(){}` method.

Comment: How can I access state of my app from other widget?